# PHP file_get_contents function not working using Cloudflare (proxy for webserver)

Tags: php, file-get-contents, cloudflare

I have been using Cloudflare for a few months now, and when I'm using Cloudflare, my payment system is not working 100%. The check script doesn't work. Without Cloudflare, everything works just fine.

The error I get is:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\check.php on line 2

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.eurobellen.nl/bel/check.php?userid=name&ip=ip&ebpin=): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\check.php on line 2

Line 2 is:

```
$ebcheck = file_get_contents("https://www.eurobellen.nl/bel/check.php?userid=name&ip=".$ip."&ebpin=".$_GET['ebpin']);
```

I have been searching around for like 2 hours and I tried several things, but I can't fix it. I hope you guys know how to fix it?

Comment: What settings do you have in cloudflare? Do they not forward query strings? Are you sure you setup things like cookies, etc, to get forwarded to your origin server correctly? (I'm not sure about cloudflare specifically, but these are common CDN issues to work through).

Comment: I used Cloudflare and CDN (Cloudfront) as well and have same problem. Did you resolve that bug and how to fix it? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can try curl for this type of tasks. `curl` is specific for that type of tasks.

```
function get_contents($url, $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1', $referer = 'http://www.google.com/') {
  if (function_exists('curl_exec')) {
    $header[0] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
  }
  else { 
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Above function checks if curl extension is installed or not. If installed then uses curl anyway it uses `file_get_contents();`