# how to get content of website URL cloud flare with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, web-crawler, cloudflare

This is my code :

```
$url = 'https://cryptoland.net/api/v1/live-price?q=selected'
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj) ;
```

when I use URL in browser manually it works fine!

but this website uses cloud flare ddos protection file_get_contents not working and shows

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

how can i solve it ?

please help me

Comment: Maybe this is relevant for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986049/php-file-get-contents-function-not-working-using-cloudflare-proxy-for-webserver

Comment: I have tested before but not working

Comment: Do this with curl which can act like a real browser.

Comment: cur return false and sometimes null